# Handle Redirects one by one with scrapy

Tags: redirect, python-2.7, scrapy, http-post

I've written a Spider which has one `start_url`. The `parse` method of my spider scraps some data and returns a list of `FormRequests`.

The problem comes with the response of that post request. It redirects me to another site with some irrelevant `GET` Parameters. The only parameter which seems to matter is a `SESSION_ID` posted along in the header. Unfortunately Scrapys behavior is to execute my requests, one after another and queues the redirect response at the end of the queue. If all returned `FormRequests` are executed, scrapy starts to execute all redirects, which all return the same site.

How can I circumvent this behavior, so that a `FormRequest` is executed, and the redirect returned in the requests response is executed befor any new `FormRequest`? Maybe there is another way, like forcing the site somehow to get a new `SESSION_ID` cookie for each FormRequest. I'm open to any idea that could probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution to this promlem. Instead of building a list of requests and return them at once, I build a chain of them and passed the next one inside the requests meta_data.

Inside the callback I pass either the next request, storing the parsed item in a spider member, or the parsed list of items if there is no next request to execute.